# Firebase Cloud Functions - onCall not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, cors, google-cloud-functions

I'm testing a very simple implementation as described on FB docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), and it's not working.

Here's my **Firebase Function,** deployed to cloud:

```
exports.getRecSkills = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return {text: data.text};
});
```

...and my **client call** (after initializing FB):

```
var getRecSkills = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getRecSkills');

getRecSkills({text: '123'}).then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error.code);
  console.log(error.message);
});
```

I get a CORS header related issue but in the docs, it doesn't mention the need for CORS... am I missing something?

[image]

Some notes:

- I've been able to execute other Firebase Functions (i.e. HTTPS,
  Database) so I don't think it's me setting up Firebase wrong.
- Updated to latest Firebase, so don't think that's an issue either.
- Gives me an "internal" error, which the API docs aren't helpful, other than "something is seriously wrong".
- I can't seem to get the function to work (it keeps giving me
  400-errors) when testing locally via the shell, even though I got it
  to work with any other database and https functions

Been struggling with this for quite some time... Please help!

Comment: What version of the client and node SDKs are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest for both - FB client (v4.13.1), and FIrebase admin (v5.12.0)

Comment: What version of firebase-functions are you using on the server?

Comment: I am deploying my functions to Firebase with v1.0.2 (the latest), which is what I assume you're asking?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I can test the function through shell, but calling it from my app doesn't work

Comment: I see that you forgot to initialize your config with projectId.. your URL has 'undefined' on it

Comment: Did you get this figured out? I'm hitting this as well.

Comment: Nope... haven't had any luck yet... So I'm realizing a few things:

1. I can't seem to get the function to work (it keeps giving me 400-errors) when testing locally via the shell, even though I got it to work with any other database and https functions.

2. The undefined seems to persist despite the fact that I'm using an initialized firebase (all my other firebase library functions work properly...) I'm not sure why this "undefined" is coming up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of your `CORS` error, make sure your `firebase.json` has the following `headers`:

```
"hosting": [
    {
      "headers": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "headers": [
            {
              "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
              "value": "*"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
   }
]
```

If you're running on **Firebase Emulator** on local device, make sure you have the following after initializing your Firebase Functions, otherwise your local device will still be calling the remote the Firebase Function and you'll hit the `CORS` error again:

```
if (window.location.hostname === "localhost") {
    console.log("localhost detected!");
    firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5001');
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem just recently but solved it after including my "projectId" in my config object. Below is a code snippet of the Firebase config object for Javascript. Make sure all fields have been filled in your config object and it should solve your undefined issue.

```
     var config = {
     apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
     authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
     databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
     projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
     storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
     messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `CORS` issues and you are using `express` in order to expose the API functions you have to allow cors:

```
import * as cors from 'cors';
import * as express from 'express';

const corsHandler = cors({origin: true});

const app = express();
app.use(corsHandler);

app.post('/createUser', async (request, response) => {
  await createUser(request, response);
});

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```